# Find the volume bounded by the following surfaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

I need to find the volume bounded by the following surfaces:

$$x^2+y^2=2z$$ $$x^2+y^2=3-z$$

I don't know how to proceed in solving this exercise, all I could think of was trying to make a system of these 2 and get $z=1$. I just wanna understand how am I supposed to proceed in finding the boundaries, no need to evaluate the integral.

Comment: Find the intersection of the two i.e. 2z=3-z. Then you know that the integration region on x,y is x^2+y^2=2. Proceed with integration.

Comment: Thanks, I have gotten to the integration region yes, but here I am unsure about the following approach i took: $x=rcos\theta ,\:y=rsin\theta $ with $0\le r\le \sqrt{2}$ and $0\le \theta \le 2\pi \:$ with the Jacobian $J=r > 0$
But before I went to this double integral for $x^2+y^2=2$ i took the boundary for $dz$ as being $\int _{3-\left(x^2+y^2\right)}^{\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}\:z\:dz$ @JakeFreeman i don't know if i took the correct approach

Comment: Can you please edit the question with what you have done and what you wrote here in comments?

Comment: Also did you try to visualize this in an online tool?

Comment: I haven't, I am not sure how, and I didn't edit the question cuz I wasn't sure if I'm spouting nonsense in my comment or not and didn't want to give people the wrong idea before anyone could verify what I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $x^2+y^2=2(3-x^2-y^2)\implies x^2+y^2=6-2x^2-2y^2\implies 3x^2+3y^2=6$, so
$x^2+y^2=2$, which gives you the circle of center $(0,0)$ and radius $\sqrt 2$. We can now compute the integral in cylindrical coordinates doing the following calculations
$$\iiint_Vdxdydz=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt 2}\int_{\frac{\rho^2}{2}}^{3-\rho^2}\rho dzd\rho d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^{\sqrt 2} \rho\bigg( 3-\frac{3\rho^2}{2}\bigg)d\rho=$$
$$=2\pi\int_0^{\sqrt 2}3\rho-\frac{3\rho^3}{2} d\rho=2\pi\cdot\frac{3\rho^2}{2}-\frac{3\rho^4}{8}\Bigg\vert_0^{\sqrt 2}=3\pi.$$